# I want to save a Firefox web page as "Web Page,html only" format using command line in Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, command-line, webpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: downloading a file from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/54628/windows-downloading-a-file-from-command-line)

I want to save a Firefox web page as "Web Page,html only" format using command line in Windows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to download this page http://example.com/index.html
just execute this

```
wget http://example.com/index.html
```